# C programming print bool

Tags: c

This is how you print a bool. One value is set true and one is set to false. Not sure why it wouldn't print before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {

    bool intersect = true;
    bool intersect1 = false;
    printf(" Intersection is %d \n", intersect);
    printf(" Intersection1 is %d \n", intersect1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have a question about why it was closed as a dupe, *please* ask in the comments, not as something edited into the question.

Comment: @Yuhao I fixed my post.

Comment: @DennisMeng I fixed my post.

Comment: Editing the answer into the question is also a no-no. If you want to answer your own question, then write a separate answer.

Comment: @DennisMeng How do I get rid of all the negative votes then?

Comment: Honestly, you probably won't be able to. Your best course of action is to learn from *why* your question was so poorly received and not make the same mistake next time you write up a question.

Comment: See also [the linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/17307275?sort=votes).

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
printf("%s", intersect ? "true" : "false");
```